# Posicionamiento de imágenes CSS

Tags: css, css3, imagen

Hola comunidad necesito posicionar una imagen como se ve la primera imagen "resultado esperado" con CSS.

[image: Resultado esperado]

[image: Intento de código]

Comment: Podrías pegar tu codigo html y css ? De esa manera sabremos en qué estás fallando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te falta la propiedad **overflow**. Con ella puedes regular la visiblidad de los contenidos que sobresalen de una caja html. En este caso con el valor **hidden** lo que haces es ocultar todo lo que salga de esa caja.

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#myDiv img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/157970/isolated/preview/c156b4270aea292b9b335dd463ea17eb-icono-de-planeta-tierra-icono-de-tierra.png" alt="">
</div>
```